Elasticsearch APM Fleet integration - index per application
We have an elasticsearch cluster with 4 data nodes.
We have our FleetServers with APM integration enabled.
We have noticed that elasticsearch creates at least an index per app / service for example:

.ds-logs-apm.app.myapp1-2024.12.19-000019
.ds-logs-apm.app.myapp2-2024.12.19-000019
.ds-logs-apm.app.myapp3-2024.12.19-000019
.ds-metrics-apm.app.myapp1-2024.12.19-000019
.ds-metrics-apm.app.myapp2-2024.12.19-000019
.ds-metrics-apm.app.myapp3-2024.12.19-000019

The result is that we hit our shards limits (4000/4000).
We were wondering if we can setup the APM integration to save all the metrics and the logs in two big indexes (one for metrics and one for logs) instead of split them per app.
if yes how to do it and what are the cons?
thank you
